# Dynamic search with HTML + JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I starting to learning html css js, I trying to show my actual location temp if the input is empty and if the input has some value show the location with new temp. My problems is, when I put the new value the page not reload properly with the data. I dont know how to repeat the Conditional Statements without reload the page. Sorry for english erros.

```html
<body>
    <h1>Sample Page</h1>
    <form class="form" name="form" id="formulario">
        <label for="title">Insira a cidade: </label>
        <input type="text" id="cidade" name="cidade">
        <button type="button" id="botao" >Enviar</button>
        <br>
        <p id="myLocation"></p>
    </form>
    <span id="windSpeed"></span>
    <span id="buscar"></span>
    </div>
    <div>

    </div>
</body>
<script src="teste.js"></script>
```

```js
var x = document.getElementById('myLocation')

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        document.getElementById('botao').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault()
        })
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function appendData(data) {
    var mainContainer = document.getElementById("windSpeed")
    mainContainer.innerHTML = 'Temperatura ' + data.main.temp + ' Cº '
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    const API_LOCAL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${position.coords.latitude}&lon=${position.coords.longitude}&appid=03838cfa6af6494abe9a10e2f9d3ef17&units=metric&lang=pt_br`

    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        redirect: 'follow'
    };

    fetch(API_LOCAL, requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => appendData(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}

function searchParams() {
    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        redirect: 'follow'
    };
    let city = document.getElementById('cidade').value
    const API_CITY = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=03838cfa6af6494abe9a10e2f9d3ef17&units=metric&lang=pt_br`
    fetch(API_CITY, requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => appendData(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}


var a = document.getElementById('cidade').value
if (a == null || a == ''){
    getLocation()
}else{
    searchParams()
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Are you trying to make an iframe the user can change to whatever they want?

Comment: Im trying to show the temp of my location as soon as the people enter the page, after that if he wants to know the temp of another city he types and search, and the api change to show the new data. But I wanna show in same element html, removing the previous data.

Comment: you say "temp" is that short for tempeture>

Comment: yes, sorry. And when I say "mylocation" is the client location.

Comment: ok, now i know a bit more and understand better. Give me a min to do some research and i might be able to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what I expected using this js function. Now when the client load the page the data shows the current information, and then if he wants search for a specific city the element  html is update to the new data.

```
<body>
    <h1>clima tempo</h1>
    <form class="form" name="form" id="formulario">
        <label for="title">Insira a cidade: </label>
        <input type="text" id="cidade" name="cidade" placeholder="cidade..">
        <button type="button" id="botao" onclick="recarregar()">Enviar</button>
        <br>
        <p id="myLocation"></p>
    </form>
    <span id="windSpeed"></span>
    <span id="buscar"></span>
    </div>
    <div>

    </div>
</body>
<script src="teste.js"></script>
```

```
function recarregar() {
    var empt = document.forms["form"]["cidade"].value
    if (empt == "") {
        getLocation()
    } else {
        searchParams()
        return true
    }
}

window.onload = recarregar
```